# KMM Cocoapods Export (M1) Mac

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

So i am trying to export my KMM project as iOS framework

here is my build.gradle.kts

```
kotlin {
   android()
   ios()
   sourceSets {
    val commonMain by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.0-RC")
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.2.1")
            implementation("com.soywiz.korlibs.klock:klock:2.2.2")
            implementation("com.ionspin.kotlin:bignum:0.3.2")
        }
    }
    val commonTest by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
            implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
        }
    }
    val androidMain by getting
    val androidTest by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
            implementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
        }
    }

    val iosX64Main by getting
    val iosArm64Main by getting
    val iosMain by getting {
        dependsOn(commonMain)
        iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
        iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
    }
    val iosTest by getting
}

cocoapods {
    framework {
        summary = "Some description for a Kotlin/Native module"
        homepage = "Link to a Kotlin/Native module homepage"
        baseName = "sharedCode"
        isStatic = false
        export(project(":sharedCode"))
        transitiveExport = true
    }
    podfile = project.file("/Users/user/Developments/SampleApp/Podfile")
    ios.deploymentTarget = "14.0"
}
}
```

here is my Podfile

```
platform :ios, '14.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Sample App' do
pod 'sharedCode', :path => '/Users/User/Developments/KotlinMultiplatform/sharedCode'
end
```

Whenever i run the gradle sync from Android Studio it will throw this error

```
Executing of 'pod install' failed with code 1.
Error message:

Please, check that file "/Users/User/Developments/SampleApp/Podfile" contains following lines in header:
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org'

Please, check that each target depended on sharedCode contains following dependencies:
```

And then i tried to run the `pod install` command from my terminal and it successfully installed the cocoapods. however during build I encounter this another problem

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sharedCode:linkPodDebugFrameworkIosArm64'.
```

> Following dependencies exported in the podDebugFramework binary are not specified as API-dependencies of a corresponding source set:

```
Project :sharedCode

Please add them in the API-dependencies and rerun the build.
```

What am I missing here? Thank you

Comment: Hello, @Foster! What do you mean by `export(project(":sharedCode"))`? If this is the module you're working on, this line is not needed. This should be used when you have another dependency(for example, some Kotlin library) which should be available from Swift or Objective-C. the `export` means these dependency's symbols will be exported to the result framework's headers.

Comment: In Path, give the path of the pod. spec file, hopefully, it will work
 Eg: 
target 'Sample App' do
pod 'sharedCode', :path => 'path of the podspec'
end

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue.
open terminal and run vim .zshrc. add LANG=en_US.UTF-8 then save it.
This resolved problem for me.